# Rails: remote: true from select_tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm calling an AJAX function from a `select_tag` like so:

```
<%= select_tag 'quantity', options_from_collection_for_select(order.options), :quantity, :quantity, order.quantity), onchange: "update_price(#{order.id}, this.value);" %>
```

And here's the function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function update_price(order_id, quantity) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/cart/" + <%= @cart_transaction.id %> + "/update_quantity",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        "order_id" : order_id,
        "quantity" : quantity },
      dataType: "html"
    });
  }
</script>
```

My `.js.erb` isn't called ever, and I suspect it's because I haven't specified `remote: true` anywhere, but since I don't have a form per se I don't know how to do that. Any help?

Relevant controller code here:

```
class CartTransactionsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  respond_to :html, :js

  before_filter :set_cart_transaction

  def update_quantity
    @order = @cart_transaction.orders.find(params[:order_id])
    @price = current_user.brand.prices
                         .where(template_id: @order.document.template.id)
                         .where(quantity: params[:quantity]).first
    @order.update_attributes(
      price_cents: @price.amount_cents, quantity: params[:quantity]
    )
    @cart_transaction.save!
    respond_to { |format| format.js }
  end

  private

  def set_cart_transaction
    @cart_transaction = current_user.cart
  end

  def cart_transactions_params
    params.require(:cart_transaction).permit(
      :name, :email, :delivery_address, :comments
    )
  end
end
```

**Update**

Here's the `.js.erb` that isn't called for some reason:

```
console.log("update_quantity.js.erb file");

$('#price_cell').html("<%= j render(partial: 'price', locals: { order: @order }) %>");
$('#subtotals').html("<%= j render(partial: 'subtotals', locals: { cart_transaction: @cart_transaction }) %>");
```

Comment: are you certain that the javascript update_price method gets called?

Comment: also, I don't see where the results of the ajax call are handled? like a success handler?

Comment: Method is definitely called, the `.js.erb` should be called by `format.js` too, right? I'll update the question with that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function update_price(order_id, quantity) {
    $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
      },
      url: "/cart/" + <%= @cart_transaction.id %> + "/update_quantity",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        "order_id" : order_id,
        "quantity" : quantity }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Dude, try my updated answer. 
I have removed dataType: "html" code in js. It means that you are sending a HTML request instead of js request.
Try removing dataType attribute in your code, it must work fine.

Comment: Ah, that did it! My HTML is a bit busted but it's loading the js now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use dataType: "script", it will work and will render js.erb